# Which version of material UI is supported with react 15.5.4?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am developing an app in react 15.5.4 and wants to use material ui. I get error react 16.3.0 or greater is required whenever I try to install and use material ui. I have checked that with different versions of material ui and not sure which version provides support for react 15.5.4 any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [change log](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.40) the first release which references React 16.3.0 is version v1.0.0-beta.40. Therefore, I would assume that v1.0.0-beta.39 is working with React 15.x.

I know that at least v1.0.0-beta.17 worked well with React 15.x.

**However, I strongly recommend to use the newest versions of React and material-ui**. There are quite a few differences in the usage of material-ui and you won't find an online documentation about the material-ui beta versions.

We recently updated a reasonably big project from using material-ui v1.0.0-beta.17 and React 15.x to the newest versions of both and it took about a day without using any helper scripts.